# Barcode scanning with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, barcode-scanner

I have a usb barcode scanner which I am connecting to my computer. Everytime it scans a barcode, it types the data into the computer like a keyboard. My goal was to have the data be typed into PyQT5 Table widget.

I have created the table below and I simply scan the items into it. The problem is that when I scan an item, it edits the first cell, but the cursor does not move automatically to the next row so I can scan a new item into the table. I have to click on the second cell and then scan the item. Then click on the third cell and scan the item and so on.

I was wondering how I can automate it so that after an item is scanned into the first cell, it automatically moves to the next cell and waits for input from the scanner?

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
   
#Main Window 
class App(QWidget): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.title = 'Specimen Dashboard'

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)    
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget() 
        self.createTable() 
        self.tableWidget.itemChanged.connect(self.go_to_next_row) 
   
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout() 
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget) 
        self.setLayout(self.layout) 

        self.show() 
   
    def go_to_next_row(self):
        #Not working
        #Trying to see if I can automatically move to next cell, but editing it 
        self.tableWidget.setItem(1,0, QTableWidgetItem("Name")) 

    #Create table 
    def createTable(self):   
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)  
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)   
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True) 
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode( 
            QHeaderView.Stretch) 

app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
ex = App() 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: AFAIK, once a code is scanned, it should also send a confirm/newline character (which, in your case, exits the edit mode of the cell), right?

Comment: I don't know why it closes right away. In excel, it works fine. I scan, it writes into the cell and automatically moves to the next cell. In PyQt5, when it encounters a newline, it just stays on the current cell

Comment: I didn't ask you that. I wanted to know if the scanner sends a return-like character after each scan.

Comment: It edits the cell and remains on the cell having it highlighted in blue. If I scan a different code right away, it automatically edits the same cell. So it is as if I pressed Enter. It does send a return-like character after each scan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the scanners send an endline("\n") that is translated a Return or Enter key and this by default closes the editor, in this case that event must be intercepted, move the cursor and open the editor:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class TableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if (
            event.key() in (QtCore.Qt.Key_Enter, QtCore.Qt.Key_Return)
            and self.state() == QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.EditingState
        ):
            index = self.moveCursor(
                QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MoveNext, QtCore.Qt.NoModifier
            )
            self.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(
                index, QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.ClearAndSelect
            )
            self.edit(index)
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.tableWidget = TableWidget(4, 2)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(
            QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'd say you should also check if the `state() == self.EditingState`, otherwise pressing enter on the keyboard without any editor opened would start editing on the next item.

Comment: @musicamante You are correct, thanks for indicating it

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass the table and overwrite [`closeEditor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#closeEditor): the `hint` argument tells the view what should happen when the editor has been closed; by default, when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> the current cell data is submitted, but you can override this behavior like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

class Table(QtWidgets.QTableView):
    # leave to False for the default behavior (the next cell is the one at the
    # right of the current, or the first of the next row; when set to True it
    # will always go to the next row, while keeping the same column
    useNextRow = False

    def closeEditor(self, editor, hint):
        if hint == QtWidgets.QAbstractItemDelegate.SubmitModelCache:
            if self.useNextRow:
                super().closeEditor(editor, hint)
                current = self.currentIndex()
                newIndex = current.sibling(current.row() + 1, current.column())
                if newIndex.isValid():
                    self.setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
                    self.edit(newIndex)
                return
            else:
                hint = QtWidgets.QAbstractItemDelegate.EditNextItem
        super().closeEditor(editor, hint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    test = Table()
    test.show()
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(10, 5)
    test.setModel(model)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```